# How to access variable in a while loop from a function in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, while-loop

I want to access the `$name` variable, which is defined in a while loop, in a function named `sendMail`. Would I have to somehow incorporate the function within the loop?

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    print_r($row); echo "<br><br>";
    $name = $row['Name'];
    $date = $row['sDate'];
    $time = $row['sTime'];
    $phone = $row['Phone'];

    $email = $row['Email'];
    sendMail($row['Email']);

    $company = $row['Company'];
    $course = $row['Course'];
    $ref = $row['Reference'];
    $optout = $row['optout'];

    echo "<tr bgcolor=#ABB5F6>
    <td>$name</td>
    <td>$date</td>
    <td>$time</td>
    <td>$phone</td>
    <td>$email</td>
    <td>$company</td>
    <td>$course</td>
    <td>$ref</td>
    <td>$optout</td>
    </tr>";
}

// Mail to $to and $emailarray recipients
function sendMail($to)
{
    $subject = 'Test mail';
    $message = 'Hello'.$name; // I want $name from the while loop
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "From:" . "myemail@email.com";
    $headerz = implode("\r\n", $headers);

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headerz);
}

?>
```

Comment: Just add sendMail($name) in the while loop (after the definition),  inside sendMail() it'll be in the $to var. Alternatively, you could pass the entire $row so you have all the values. sendMail($row)

Comment: You can access and set variables, and call functions, but you can't call a variable. The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just pass the $name to the function sendMail:

```
// Mail to $to and $emailarray recipients
function sendMail($to, $name)
{
    $subject = 'Test mail';
    $message = 'Hello'.$name; // I want $name from the while loop
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "From:" . "myemail@email.com";
    $headerz = implode("\r\n", $headers);

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headerz);
}
```

And then call the sendMail function with the name variable?

Answer (score 5):

Either make `sendMail()` accept an array (ie. `$row), or add another parameter to`sendMail()`which is called`$name` and pass it in.

ie.

```
function sendMail($to, $name)
```

called like:

```
sendMail($row['Email'], $row['Name']);
```

The parameter is probably easiest, don't go down the route of globals. I would suggest not using the array either, as the format is undefined and could change if your table structure does. If you were to use `mysql_fetch_object` with a strongly defined class, then this would be the most acceptable solution (well, using PDO/MySQLi also, of course)... Especially if you're planning on extending to use more data off `$row` in the future.

Answer (score 5):

why not just pass it ?

```
function sendMail($to, $name);
```

and call

```
sendMail($row['Email'], $row['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made the changes required in order to have your code working.

```
<?php
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                print_r($row); echo "<br><br>";
                $name = $row['Name'];
                $date = $row['sDate'];
                $time = $row['sTime'];
                $phone = $row['Phone'];

                $email = $row['Email'];

                // i added name as a parameter
                sendMail($row['Email'],$name);

                $company = $row['Company'];
                $course = $row['Course'];
                $ref = $row['Reference'];
                $optout = $row['optout'];

                echo "<tr bgcolor=#ABB5F6>
                <td>$name</td>
                <td>$date</td>
                <td>$time</td>
                <td>$phone</td>
                <td>$email</td>
                <td>$company</td>
                <td>$course</td>
                <td>$ref</td>
                <td>$optout</td>
                </tr>";

            }

            // Mail to $to and $emailarray recipients
            // i added name as a parameter
            function sendMail($to,$name)
            {
                $subject = 'Test mail';
                $message = 'Hello'.$name; // I want $name from the while loop
                $headers = array();
                $headers[] = "From:" . "myemail@email.com";
                $headerz = implode("\r\n", $headers);

                mail($to, $subject, $message, $headerz);
            }

            ?>
```